# Significato di "di comparse fuoco e paglia"

Tags: word-meaning

Nella canzone Cantare è d'amore di Amedeo Minghi c'è la frase "di comparse fuoco e paglia". Cosa significa? in questo contesto "arsure come di battaglia,
di comparse fuoco e paglia"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Come una finzione non del sangue ma del rosso*
>
> *Acqua e sale e non le lacrime assaggiai*
>
> *Arsure come di battaglia*
>
> *Di comparse, fuoco e paglia.*

Questo l'inizio del testo.

È un testo poetico alle volte un po' criptico.

Non credo che dopo *battaglia* ci vada la virgola, *di comparse* va con *di battaglia*: parafrasando, *arsure di battaglia di comparse, fuoco e paglia*.

Si parla di una finzione, una battagla di comparse come su un set cinematografico, i cui incendi sono solo *fuoco e paglia*.

Almeno questa mi sembra l'interpretazione più ovvia, ma, appunto, il testo è in parte cripitico, artificioso.

Comment: Sinonimi di comparse?

Comment: Non so, dipende che uso ne devi fare. Si può dire 'figurante', nel cinema e teatro. Non mi vengono altri sinonimi,  se ti serve puoi trovare qualche perifrasi.